# Create and edit .cpp file in command line

Tags: command-line, notepad++, putty

I've been trying to setup Notepad++ with my school's computer lab so that I can access their compiler remotely and write C++ scripts in the application, but so far I've only managed to connect to my student server through PuTTY.
I can access all of my files on my account through command line however, and was wondering if there was a method to create and edit .cpp files in command line.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be text editors available/installed for whatever platform you are connecting to via PuTTY. Perhaps, nano, vi and emacs.

Comment: What sort of system are you connecting to (Unix? Linux?).  It depends on the compilers (g++) and editors available.

Comment: Also c++ source code is not called called a script.

Comment: Proof we live in a much more tolerant society. Time was mentioning vi and emacs in the same breath would have gotten a coder killed for witchcraft and devil worship.

Comment: As a student, you can get compilers for free and install them on your own machine and work locally, it is much simpler. Also, if you can access the school's computer via `ssh/putty`, you could install FileZilla locally (it's an FTP/ssh/scp client) and connect to school and then select a file on the school's server and right-click and edit it in Notepad locally and FileZilla will copy the file back when you are finished.

Comment: I feel I haven't been descriptive enough, this is the only way I can access the other computer remotely:
http://imgur.com/a/BrZrg
I can't share any files or anything over, at least I don't think so.

Comment: Looks like unix or linux. My first comment stands. I would expect that one or more of the editors I mentioned is installed.

Comment: Try with an SCP client - e.g. WinSCP. If you can connect via ssh (Putty), you should be able to transfer files via SCP.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out so quickly.
Could SCP and vi be elaborated on? I tried the vi command before and I found it incredibly difficult to work with.

Also emac, nano, etc

Comment: That is why I suggested nano. Although that may not be installed.

Comment: SCP is about pushing your local files up to the server from your machine. You edit locally with your favorite c++ IDE then copy to the server possibly using filezilla or WinSCP.

Comment: Yes, vi(m) is great, I'm using it all the time. I still remember the first time I started it by mistake and I wasn't able to even exit it, so I had to kill it from another console :D

Comment: https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye Is this a proper guide on the use of the SCP command?

Comment: @ThomasAhrens The "normal" Unix editors, emacs and `<deep breath/>` vi, are from a different era. They have incredibly steep learning curves. Both are worth learning when you have the time. (Emacs can even edit files over ssh as if they were local.)

Comment: You would use the SCP command line usually only if working Linux/Linux. For Windows/Linux as said I'd recommend the WinSCP client.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think I'll take the time to learn that method, then, especially if this issue can't be fixed by technical at my school (also sorry for wrong use of terms, I've never been very good with terminology).

Comment: Also could someone explain to me why the command line window just starts slowing down after only a few minutes of use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes just make a folder like this:

```
mkdir myCode
```

Then create the text file and write it with vim (or nano if you find vim hard):

```
vi myCode/main.cpp
```

or

```
nano myCode/main.cpp
```